# OpenLDAP encrypt database or by attributes

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, ldap

I run an OpenLDAP server on which there is some data I wanted to encrypt.
I cannot use a userPassword like attributes as this is hash. In my case I need to crypt/decrypt it with a secret key.

But if I do so, i'll not be able anymore to perform ldapsearch request with these attributes in my filter (as they are encrypted...)

So, is there a natif way to be it on a attribute basis ?
Or maybe there is a way to encrypt the whole data.mdb file to avoid someone who stole it to read it on it's own instance.

Thank you